# Can you add multiple facebook comments to a single webpage?

Tags: facebook, comments

Is it possible to add multiple facebook comment boxes to a single webpage?  When you copy the code to place on a webpage, it sets each comment box for a single page.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the fb:comments class, make sure data-href is unique for each box. For example, a blog could make data-href a link to each blog post the box corresponds to.